# activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Considering the following scenario:

1. Create MyCodeActivity1 with argument MyArgument1
2. Add this activity to a myworkflow.xaml
3. Rename MyArgument1 in MyCodeActivity1 to MyRenamedArgument1

If you open myworkflow.xaml, visual studio will show this error:

> activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML

Is there a facility where visual studio can give more information about the error please?
For now I have created a small windows application that tries to execute the workflow and shows an error message if invalid. This does give a clear message. But it would be great if visual studio provided this functionality directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another reason for the error "activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML", is bad dlls. So check the project references for any yellow triangle, or check the history of the project.

Answer (score 12):

No.

Nope.

Nuh uh.

Visual Studio's refactoring can't handle **change in Activity code => change in XamlAppDef XML**.  Its not surprising, such a chain of logic would be complex to achieve.  So *whenever you do this* you *must expect your workflows will have to be fixed*.  Either plan ahead, or...

Any time a workflow won't compile, or if it shows the *red box of pain* in the design surface, you should always right click on the workflow file, select **Open With...** and select the **XML (text) editor**.  You will see the squiggly error lines and more detail about the error in this view.

Comment: The red box of pain ... :) Very appropriate heh

Comment: I have the same issue in Visual Studio 2019, And the XML (text) editor doesn't show any squiggly error lines! Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: @Jedidja did you have the same issue in 2013 :-)?

Comment: @MeysamKarimi I believe so...although it's a bit tough to remember 10 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error("activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML"), But in my case, I had created a Code Activity and used that in a State Machine. But, I found out that the defined Code Activity had not been shown in the Toolbox. It means that the Code Activity is not identifiable to Windows Work Flow.